# How do you use SaveChanges() method in Ado.net Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I set up an IDataContext and when i create a data class for an entity, i inherit it from IDataContext.

IDataContext interface has 4 methods.

```
IQueryable<T> GetAll();
T GetById(long id);
void Add(T entity);
void Delete(T entity);
void Save(T entity);
```

As you know Delete and Save methods have this structure;

```
FooEntities db = new FooEntities();

db.DeleteObject(Foo entity);
// or save changes method
db.SaveChanges();
```

I meant these two methods could be generalized or something...

My question is how and where do you use these two methods.

- Inside of the each data class for an entity
- or another way of using.

Comment: What is this `IDataContext` you're talking about? It doesn't appear to be a standard part of EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can abstract away the details of the framework with the Repository pattern. Here is an [example implementation](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/kim/archive/2008/11/12/data-access-with-the-entity-framework.aspx) of IRepository for the Entity Framework. As for where to invoke the actual deleting and saving, your Controller/Presenter is a likely candidate.

Answer (score 0):

DeleteObject is used to delete an object from the store.  Calling DeleteObject as you have above *marks the object as deleted.*  The call to SaveChanges() actually commits that change to the database.  Both are necessary to delete an object from the store.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is not what i am asking for.
Please take a look at the Aidan's answer

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question.  Aidan is right, the Repository pattern is a good method for wrapping and consolidating EF.  Here is another good article on that: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImplRepositoryPatternEF.aspx